# How to change the document's HTML of the app under test (AUT)?

Tags: cypress

I am trying to rewrite the complete page under test to include local content. I was trying to grab the html element and replace it all. I have base64 data to add for an image, but I would like to see text working as a start.

Visiting a local HTML file is not working. Looking for a workaround.

```
cy.visit('/')
cy.get('html')
    .invoke('attr', 'innerHTML', '<head></head><body><h1>Hello</h1><body>')
```

Answer (score 8):

**NOTE:** if you're simply trying to test files on your local filesystem, have a look at setting up a simple static-file server, e.g. [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), and start it up before running Cypress.

With that being said, here's an answer how to manually change the HTML during test, which may still prove useful for certain scenarios.

---

`.invoke('attr')` calls jQuery's [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method which sets an HTML *attribute* on the `html` (`document.documentElement`) element.

<sup>(Sidenote: where is the jQuery coming from? Cypress wraps DOM elements yielded from DOM-based Cypress commands into jQuery object so that you can further use jQuery methods on those elements. In fact, the `cy.get(selector)` uses jQuery for selecting, thus you can use any jQuery-compatible selectors in the `cy.get` command).</sup>

To set its `innerHTML`, you don't want to set an *attribute*, but its DOM *property* --- thus invoke jQuery's [`prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```js
cy.get('html').invoke('prop', 'innerHTML', '<head></head><body><h1>Hello</h1><body>');
```

Or better yet, use jQuery's [html](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method:

```js
cy.get('html').invoke('html', '<head></head><body><h1>Hello</h1><body>');
```

Btw, you can also manipulate the document HTML in a callback *without* jQuery, if you end up needing more control:

```js
cy.document().then( document => {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = `
        <style>.item { color: red }</style>
        <body>
            <div class="item">hello</div>
        </body>
    `;
});
```

That being said, if you're setting just contents, I'd manipulate `body` element:

```js
cy.get('body').invoke('html', '<div>oi!</div>');
// or
cy.document().then( document => {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<div>hello</div>';
});
```

Comment: using .invoke('prop', 'innerHTML') is powerful because it can give you access to the entire HTML of your document which you may want to save or inspect.